# Why does the text displayed on applet doesn't change on "keydown" or "keyup" events?

Tags: java, applet, keydown, japplet, keyup

I wanted to change the displayed string from "start" to "keyup" or "keydown" but the string doesnt seem to change..

```
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Applet extends JApplet {
    String str = "start..";
    public void init() {
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString(str, 200, 200);
    }
    public boolean keyDown(Event evt , int key) {
        str = "keyDown";
        repaint();

        return true;
    }
    public boolean keyUp(Event evt , int key) {
        str = "keyUp";

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what do you want to say?

Comment: Also, you'll not want to name your class "Applet" since this is already a name used for a core Java class. To avoid confusing others now, and more importantly yourself later, you'll want to give it a more unique name. Also, I am guessing that you want your program to respond to key presses and releases, but we won't know for sure unless you tell us, and show us the code you've written to try to implement this behavior. And if so, have you looked at the Java Swing tutorials on how to respond to key events including how to write key listeners and use key bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use methods that were deprecated in **Java 1.1.** Instead implement a [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) or use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).
2. Ensure the applet is focusable & has the input focus.

### E.G. using `KeyListener`

[image: KeyApplet]

```
// <applet code='KeyApplet' width=200 height=40></applet>
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class KeyApplet extends JApplet implements KeyListener {

    String str = "start..";

    public void init() {
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(str, 20, 20);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        str = "keyDown";
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
        str = "keyUp";
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggestion Key Bindings. -1 for an SSCCE that overrides the paint() method since custom painting should be done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel (or JComponent) and then add the panel to the applet.

Comment: @camickr  Fair call.  I was considering factoring the painting into a panel, but wanted to get the basics clear first.